# Python PyCharm Error Highlighting Default Setup

Tags: python, pycharm

I am using PyCharm as my Python IDE.

I have a problem dealing with the error highlighting.

By default, PyCharm highlights all problems, but there are 2 other options, Syntax and None.

I want to make Syntax as my default highlighting, but I don't know how.

I also want to know how to set all my existing python files (about 40+) to have a highlighting of Syntax too. I can do this one by one individually but I don't know how to do them at once.

Thank you for all future answering my questions.

Edited/Added:
My question was asking about the 3 options of the error highlighting of the Python IDE named PyCharm for Python 3.
I know that the default option is "All problems" for all newly-created python files, but what I want to do is to set the default option to be "Only Syntax" instead of "All problems" for all newly-created python files so that I don't have to change the options manually.
It would be great if there is a way to change all the existing python files's error highlighting to be "Syntax" from other options.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGx7V.png)

Comment: Could you please attach a screenshot how `None` highlighting looks like? By default all python files are highlighted.

Comment: The 3 options are on top-right of the image.

Comment: Yeah, I attached that, the top-right side of the image shows those 3 options.